# Customize Authentication - Login Symfony2 Messages

Tags: authentication, symfony, message, customization

So I'm reading the security chapter of Symfony2 Book. I understand everything, but I'd like to customize the error message if a there is a login error.

In which file can I change this?

This is the template:

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

{#
    If you want to control the URL the user is redirected to on success (more details below)
    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
#}

<input type="submit" name="login" />
```

I believe the worst way of doing this would be something like:

```
if (error.message=="Bad credentials")
    echo "Los datos son erróneos :)"

if (error.message==The presented password is invalid")
    echo "La combinación username/password no es correcta :)"
```

Would you help me please?

---

**Edit:** I got it working:

In case someone needs to do this, be sure you add this line to the config.yml

```
#app/config/config.yml
framework:
    translator: { fallback: en }
```

and put in the file messages.whateverisyourlanguage.yml, in my case messages.es.yml, lines like this one:

Text you want to translate : Translated text

```
#Foo\DummyBundle\Resources\translations\messages.es.yml
The presented password cannot be empty.: El campo contrasena no debe estar vacio
The presented password is invalid.: Los datos suministrados son incorrectos
Bad credentials: Los datos suministrados son incorrectos
```

Be careful with the text you want to translate. If the text has a dot at the end, you have to put the dot. I wasn't doing that and it wasn't working.

`footranslate.` is different than `footranslate`

Greetings! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [translation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html). In `parameters.ini` [set locale](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html#the-translation-process) to your language and create [message file](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html#translation-locations-and-naming-conventions). Then in twig template use:

```
{% if error %}
    <div class="error">{{ error.message|trans({},'messages') }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Well thanks. Now, where can I find all of the error messages a login form should throw?
I believe I have to put exactly the message that will appear on the message file, so I could translate them all, but I'm not sure which messages are them.

Comment: There are only few messages – check out exception messages in files located in `./vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/`

Comment: There are messages here too: vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker.php

Answer (score 5):

There is another possibility if you don't want to use translations. You can just replace the message, for example:

```
{{ error.message | replace({"Bad credentials." : "Invalid username or password."}) }}
```