# Symfony 2 Login Validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

The Symfony 2 documentation, shows you how to create a form based on an entity and validate it in a controller on submission to ensure certain fields had been populated on the server side.

However when looking at the documentation for authentication, it uses a very different approach to create and process the form, where you simple define a route for check_login  without a controller declaration, as it is taken care of by the security bundle.

Because the login/authentication check is now handeld by the security bundle, you have no way to implement any validation in a controller like the form validation documentation shows.

Without the HTML5 required tag, you are able to spam the login form with empty inputs.

How do I added form validation for email and password fields based on the Symfony authentication documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-encoding-user-password

Also the error when submitting incorrect credentials simple says 'Invalid Credentials', how do I customise this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are Symfony2 documentation sections that exactly cover your issue. One is about the actual [login form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-form-login) and the other covers [how you can customize it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html).

The validation happens completely on the site of Symfony2. You don't have to worry about that. You just need to create a controller for displaying the login form and possible errors. In addition an [entity provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) can be used to use dynamically created users (stored in database).

And finally you can customize the error message by making use of the [translating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201849/customize-authentication-login-symfony2-messages).

Comment: sorry i wrongly upvoted. this answer ain't helping. :(