# How to translate SecurityContext:AUTHENTICATION_ERROR?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I'm using FosUserBundle with Symfony2.1 and when I try to connect a user that is not enabled, the following error is displayed on my form : `User account is disabled`, which is great but it is a French website and I would like to translate this message in french.

I've already translated session messages and validators in translations folder : `messages.fr.yml` and `validators.fr.yml` and `MyUserBundle.fr.yml` but I can't get the ones created by the SecurityContext.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customize Authentication - Login Symfony2 Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201849/customize-authentication-login-symfony2-messages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All messages from FOSUserBundle are using "FOSUserBundle" as the message domain. So you have to put your translation into `./app/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.fr.yml`.

If you've derived your own bundle based on [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md) the file goes into `./src/YourUserBundle/Resources/translations/FOSUserBundle.fr.yml`.