# How to set error messages in specific cases in symfony2 login_check

Tags: security, symfony

How can I write specific error message in symfony2 when login failed depend on the situation

For example: 
**When username is not found:** 
The username 'userxxx' doest not exist.
**When username is found but password is wrong:**
The password you've entered is wrong! Please try again!
Or: The password for 'userxxx' is wrong! Please try again!

I found a way to alert error message when the username is not found is write a custom userprovider

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username) {
        $user = $this->entityManager
                ->getRepository('ShopSecurityBundle:User')
                ->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));        
        if ($user) {
            $service_user = new SecurityServiceUser($user->getUsername(), $user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt(), array($user->getRole()));
            //var_dump($service_user); die;
            return $service_user;
        }
        // I throw a BadCredentialsException() here then the error message in security Context will be changed arcodding to the exception message!
        throw new BadCredentialsException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist', $username));
    }
// ...
}
```

But I dont know how to change the error message when the password is wrong while the username is correct!

Any suggestion?

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201849/customize-authentication-login-symfony2-messages/9206552#9206552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean solution would be adding errors to your form-fields 'username' and 'password' or directly to your form to display a general 'error'.

The quick solution is just passing a variable i.e. 'error' to twig ( as FOSUserBundle does ).

Throw an exception corresponding to your authentication errorr and catch it with a listener.

See how FOSUserBundle solves this in [FOSUserBundle\Security\UserProvider](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Security/UserProvider.php) and [Controller\SecurityController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php).

An example on how catch the exception in your Listener can be found in the documentation chapter [How to create a custom Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-listener). ( look at the handle method )

An overview of symfony's security exceptions can be found [here](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception.html).