# FOSUserBundle: Admin should have to activate User

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to change the Code of FOSUserbundle to have the following process:

1. User registers
2. User activates Account via E-Mail (Admin gets an E-Mail)
3. Admin activates Users

What I've done?

- Installed Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle
- Activated E-Mail confirmation

I know that there is the possibility to change the Entity to return "false" by "isEnabled()" or "isLocked()". But i also need correct Error-Messages so if an User got locked - there should be "Your account got locked please contact the Admin!" and if the Account is not activated by an Admin there should be the Message "Your Account needs to be reviewed and activated by an Admin".

Where to "hook" in - to get this Working?

Answer (score 0):

Use the event subscriber. Define it in the service definition and implement the EventSubscriberInterface. I know the docs are thin on this but if you search for FosUser event subscriber you will find plenty of help.

If all you want to do is to change the messages then check this
[Customize Authentication - Login Symfony2 Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201849/customize-authentication-login-symfony2-messages)

Comment: I can only find "SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN" as potentially useful Event - but i think the authentication / login is already done? Or can i let it fail at this point? Don't find something - also with Google ...